# what to do after registering and enqueing a css file inside a plugin folder to use it

Tags: wordpress

I have been looking for an answer for this in SOF but didn't find a clear answer

I have a plugin that forces pages to be shown when certain conditions are met. but when i try to include css files for styling i get no response .

I tried to include the file using normal html and this was a failure

then tried the `wp_register_style` and `wp_enqueue_style` as such:

```
function rw_add_style(){

$rw_path = plugins_url('kawaleb/style.css');
wp_register_style('testili',plugins_url('kawaleb/style.css'));
wp_enqueue_style( 'testili' );

}

add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts','rw_add_style');

wp_enqueue_style( 'testili' );
}
```

I placed this code on the page that should be shown when the conditions are met

What I don't know here is how to procede after enqueing !

do I need to use html to include the stylesheet file ( and then what is the use of enqueing ?) or does it do that by itself (and then what I am missing here ? )

In the doc of codex they dont go further than telling you to register the style then enqueue it !!!

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to register the style, you can just enqueue it. Also, you mentioned that you've put the code in the file where you'd like it to display, you should put it in the index file of your plugin, so in /your-plugin/index.php or whatever the main file is called, add this code:

```
function rw_add_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'testili', plugins_url( 'kawaleb/style.css' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rw_add_style' );
```

If you need it only on a certain page then you should add your conditional within the function, so you could do this for example:

```
function rw_add_style() {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->post_name == 'post_name' ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'testili', plugins_url( 'kawaleb/style.css' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rw_add_style' );
```

And you can work out what the post name is for the page you need to enqueue it for by temporarily adding the following code to the page template:

```
global $post;
echo $post->post_name;
```

To be clear, you don't need to add any html `<link>` to include the CSS as you're right, there would be no point in enqueuing it then. Just add the enqueue as I described above in the main index file of your plugin and it will be automatically included in the wp_head() in your header and output just before the `</head>`.

I hope this helps. Good luck. =)

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) but is it obligatory that i enqueue the file on the index file of my plugin ? this page is a template that i show when a condition is met ! is it bad or wrong to enqueue on the template file ? if it doesn't work on a template file then it shouldn't on index i think :/ i haven't tried it cause i am not in front of my file right now :)

Comment: Hi,

You don't have to enqueue it in your index, I just think it's cleaner to keep view code separate from logic, similar to why themes have functions.php files so that they can keep functions separate.

I realise that you only show the template when a condition is met, is there any reason you can't include that same condition around the enqueue?

How are you including the template? If it's by 'get_template()', it might be too late, meaning that you've missed the enqueue action hence why it's not outputting. Just try it out in your index to see if it works then worry about where to put it. =)

Comment: #davidnknight well i use the "template_include" filter to show the template page that is in the plugin dir when for example a user wants to show the home page . in the template page i am enqueing the css file . and the thing that i forgot is to add the get_header() in the template file . i thought that i didn't need it for the stylesheet to load . i included it ant it now works :) so get_header is the other thing that you need to uses besides enqueueing as it works as the container of the style .